# How to position overflown 'divs' side by side

Tags: css, css-float

[**DEMO HERE**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/dtmxjeir)

I have two divs in a container. Both divs have 100% and 100% height. How do I position those divs side by side?

I tried `float:left` and `display:inline-block` but nothing seems to work. Second `div` is always under first `div`, not side by side

P.S. I don't want to use absolute position and I want one `div` overflown.

Comment: is setting `width:50%;` for `.innerDivs`, acceptable?

Comment: @melc nope, whats the point if we can fit both divs in that container. I want one div overflown and sill positioned side by side

Comment: Two divs with `width 100%` won't sit side by side within their parent div unless you position a div absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

If both of them has 100% width you can't get the second one side by side. You should use "width: 50%" in those divs (I suppose they didn't have margins or padding), and then "float:left" the first one. The second one should go to the right of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add both div side by side you can not set div `width 100%`, you can set `width 50%` to check both are side by side without using `display:inline-block`

```
.innerDivs{
   width:50%;   // Change 100% to 50%
   height:100%;
   float:left;
}
```

Check this <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CZTah/)**</kbd>

---

You should add **`overflow:hidden;`** property in **outer div** to solve this

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CZTah/1/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<div style="width:300px;height:100px;border:3px solid black;margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="innerDivs" style="background:orange"></div>
  <div class="innerDivs" style="background:red"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.innerDivs{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  float:left; 
}
```

Comment: whats the point if we can fit both divs in that container. I want one div overflown and sill positioned side by side

Comment: I cant see second div now.

Comment: no i m not finding solution its goes to hidden is a solution. how to show outside with both class name same and not use display inline block then. and what is your actually goal for you want this.?